# How to use stanford nlp library in java?

Tags: java, text-mining, lemmatization

Does anyone know how to use a stanford nlp library for lemmatization. It is giving a maven framework style. However, I only just wanted to use in normal library. I have imported the nlp libraries. However, it is giving me a ClassNotFoundException.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Any idea on what minimum libraries are required to add for this lemmatizer?

Comment: Well, [`slf4j`](http://www.slf4j.org/), for start. :)

Comment: stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-sources.jar
stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models.jar
stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-javadoc.jar
stanford-corenlp-3.6.0.jar
There are the libraries that I currently added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create java project using Maven.
And add following dependency:

For SBT:`"edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.6.0",
"edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.6.0" classifier "models",
"edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-parser" % "3.6.0"`

Note: In your case use Maven. Above 3 dependency enough for core NLP.
But for your Exception use :
Maven org.slf4j dependency or include org.slf4j jar in your project.

Comment: i would like to create a normal java without maven